What are the steps to package and push a .net 2.0 standard library as a nuget package in Azure DevOps build pipeline?
This is what i have so far:
  - job: Library
pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1        
  
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        restoreDirectory: '../src/packages'
    - task: MSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: 'src/Library.Core/Library.Core.csproj'
        msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
        platform: 'Any CPU'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'pack'
        packagesToPack: 'src/Library.Core/Library.Core.csproj'
        versioningScheme: 'off'

For context, I have a library that targets .net 2.0 standard. It has all the core logic for a background service. I have also built 2 background services. These services consume the library. At the moment they basically just call a single service method from the library. They both do the same thing, but set up so that the call can be made successfully based on the different types of project.
This was done because it may be deployed in multiple environments.

A windows service project targeting .net framework 4.7.2
A worker service targeting .net core 3.1

I know they are old, but that is the potential limitation of where they are to be deployed.
I was told to package the library into a nuget package in the build pipeline and push it to a feed.

You shared what you have, but you haven't explained what isn't working or what attempts you've made to solve whatever issue it is that you're having.

You need at least one more task to publish the package - see Publish NuGet packages with Azure Pipelines.

@DanielMann, I wanted to confirm if the tasks I have so far are correct.

@RuiJarimba, thanks. yes I know that the publish step is missing. Clicking on the link you added gave me a hint though.  This:                                                                                   DotNetCore and DotNetStandard packages should be packaged with the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to avoid System.InvalidCastExceptions. See .NET Core CLI task for more details.

@Davia, Have tried as the steps mentioned in my answer below? Is it working for you?

Below is a sample contains the basic steps to build, pack and push a .NET Standard 2.0 class library to Azure Artifacts feed:

We can use a .nuspec file to define the metadata of the package. It will be used on the NuGet pack step. The .nuspec file generally is put in the root of the project directory.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MCL</id>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <authors>Bright Ran</authors>
    <copyright>Copyright © 2024 BrightRan. All Rights Reserved.</copyright>
    <description>A .NET Standard 2.0 class library written by C#.</description>
  </metadata>
  <!--
    Set the files need to be contained in the package.
    The 'src' is the relative path of the files under the project root directory.
    The 'target' is the relative path of the files within the packed package.
  -->
  <files>
    <file src="bin/Any CPU/Release/netstandard2.0/*.dll" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
    <file src="bin/Any CPU/Release/netstandard2.0/*.pdb" target="lib/netstandard2.0" />
  </files>
</package>



The pipeline YAML.

# azure-pipelines.yml

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build Package'
  inputs:
    solution: 'MCL/MCL.csproj'
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    platform: 'Any CPU'
    configuration: 'Release'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Pack Package'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: 'MCL/MCL.nuspec'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Push Package'
  inputs:
    command: push
    publishVstsFeed: 'myFeed'


The result.




